# How can i use multiple delimiters in Array List

Tags: c#, asp.net, split, delimiter

I want to ask you about the below code:

```
 string[] seledCats = new string[0];

 string condsCats = EzCoding.Web.UI.QueryStringParsing.GetValue(
   "CondsCats",
   EzCoding.Web.RequestMethod.Post);

 if (condsCats != null)
 {
     seledCats = condsCats.Split(new string[] { "," },
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 }
```

After insert the selected data in the array list, output like that `A1,A2,` 
But I want to show it like that this one `'A1','A2'`

So, How can i do it ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this little LINQ query:

```
string condsCats = EzCoding.Web.UI.QueryStringParsing.GetValue("CondsCats",EzCoding.Web.RequestMethod.Post);
string[] seledCats = null;
if(condsCats != null)
    seledCats = condsCats 
        .Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(s => String.Format("'{0}'", s))
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think `var condsCats` is a `string` not a `string[]`. Why should he split an array?

Comment: But now you putting it in condsCats

Answer (score 0):

```
seledCats = condsCats.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string s = "'" + string.Join("','", seledCats) + "'";
//to split into array again...
seledCats = condsCats.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add a leading ,  ? :)

Comment: nope, join adds specified string between array elements.

Comment: Yup, good ol' `String.Join()`. He didn't ask for the space behind the comma, though.

Comment: @Nyerguds That space is added  automatically :)

Comment: @Nino No, I mean in `"', '"` - you add a space behind every inserted comma.

Comment: @Nyerguds I did understand you... I wanted to say that I'm automatically adding space after every interpunction. It's a habit :)

Comment: You realize that depending on the situation this just means the data requires more cleanup by whatever parses it, right? Though I have a sneaky suspicion this is going to get used to feed old Bobby Tables.

Comment: Probably, but that is not the point. It's like you said to OP "you should wrap this code in try-catch"... I'm looking at this in a way that we all, with our answers, gave an idea to OP. It's up to him to implement that in good and purposeful way, not just to c/p the answer's code.

Comment: ... and i have removed the unnecessary space in Join()